# Show number of filtered entries in SmartTable

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using the regular `st-search` directive for `st-table` to filter my smart table.

Is it somehow possible to display the number of entries which match this filter? There seems to only be access to the total number entries (`entries`) as well as the ones currently shown in the paginator (`entries_displayed`).

EDIT: minimal example:

```
<table st-table="entries_displayed" st-safe-src="entries">
    ...  <input st-search=""/> ...
</table
```

Comment: use length of display collection

Comment: Do you mean `entries_displayed` in the example below? With that, I get wrong results if pagination is used.

Comment: yes , that was what I was thinking. It works when no pagination used. Suggest checking in github issue tracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been implemented recently, the controller now has a method `getFilteredCollection`.

https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/261