# Angular JS Smart Table Filtered collection

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Where is the filtered collection after filtered value in smart table.

the table is bound with `rowCollection`.

```
<table st-safe-src="rowCollection" st-table="displayed" class="table table-bordered">
```

and i have used a search filter:

```
<input type="text" id="regionFilter" st-search="region" />
```

after the result are filtered i still see all records in `rowCollection`

Comment: in your repeater are you using displayed or rowCollection ?

Comment: i am using displayed.

Comment: This may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985412/show-number-of-filtered-entries-in-smarttable

Answer (score 7):

You can create a directive to access the get the filtered Collection.  For example:

**HTML:**

```
<table 
    st-table="displayedCollection" 
    st-safe-src="rowCollection" 
    on-filter="onFilter">
```

**Javascript:**

```
//
// Create a directive
//
angular.module("smart-table").directive('onFilter', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
            onFilter: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ctrl.tableState().search;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                scope.onFilter(ctrl);
            }, true);
        }
    };
});

//
// In your controller
//
$scope.onFilter = function (stCtrl) {
    var filtered = stCtrl.getFilteredCollection();
}
```